# Understanding how Distinct() works with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, distinct

I understand that `Distinct()` *returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default equality comparer to compare values.* But I don't quite understand how this works in Entity Framework.

For example, if I have:

```
return dbContext.Products.Select(p => p.Dealer).Distinct();
```

How would the generated SQL decide if a `Dealer` equals another `Dealer`? Does it compare all the columns, or do something else?

Comment: Why would it work differently with the Entity Framework? It works like described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0 and you can overwrite the `Equals()` method.

Comment: @TonyStark: Because the default comparer compares the address of each object, and that has no meaning in SQL. Also, you cannot override `Equals()` in SQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework 6 query with Distinct filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595253/entity-framework-6-query-with-distinct-filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LINQ Distinct() is mapped to `SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3,....`,

Which is semantically different than in IEnumerable.Distinct().  But the other options are simply useless, and this query pattern in SQL is occasionally useful.

I would typically expect to see it in queries like

```
var col = db.Products.Select(p => new {p.Color, p.Size, p.Material}).Distinct();
```

And anonymous types have a built-in property-wise comparer, so the in-memory implementation and the SQL translation agree.

Comment: Thanks. But this kind of shifts the question to SQL. In your example, would all three properties (`Color`, `Size`, and `Material`) all need to match before `Distinct()` decided two instances were the same?

Comment: Yes, that's what `SELECT DISTINCT` means in SQL.