# WPF Itemscontrol shows duplicate entries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I'm using an ItemControl to display a list of strings (like a suggestion-list).
My problem is that it sometimes duplicates one entry..

I've tried to disable virtualization without success...

this is my xaml-code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ResultList}">              
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsVirtualizing="False" IsContainerVirtualizable="False" VirtualizationMode="Standard"></VirtualizingStackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button>
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"></TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>                                       
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

[image]

as you can see there are 3 strings shown but I only have 2 in my binding-ResultList...(Ergebnisse 2 is bound to the ResultList.Count)

ResultList is of type ObservableCollection().

Comment: Does it always duplicate items, or only sometimes?  What kind of object is `ResultList`?

Comment: For sur you have 2 items with the same displayname ;)

Comment: ResultList is: ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject>()

Comment: Please provide a repo of your issue if you want any help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This question [Entity Framework select distinct name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4539668/2084193) and its answers may help

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution for that problem.

These duplicate items are only shown when I put my listbox in a popup (to simulate a suggestion-field).

The only thing I had to do was adding this line of code after I changed the entries of ResultList to Refresh the list.

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(field.ResultList).Refresh();
```

Comment: This solution is poor. It heals only symptoms not cause itself.

Comment: feel free to provide a solution for that.

Comment: I'm not able to provide a solution without seeing anything but xaml. Duplicates are not generated by virtualization. And I'm not pointing this out to make you feel bad in any way. The solution that you have provided by yourself won't stop code from creating duplicates. It's gonna create duplicate and then remove it. Best option would be to NOT creating duplicates at all.